# How does this phrase choose between the imperfective and the preterite?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto

I came across a sentence I find interesting in Ezequiel Adamovsky's book *Historia de la Argentina*:

```
Antes de la Conquista no había «Argentina», como tampoco hubo una «Argentina colonial».
```

Why does the first half use the imperfective *había* while the second half uses the preterite, *hubo*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En los textos narrativos suele usarse el pretérito imperfecto para describir el fondo, ambientación y contexto en un determinado período de tiempo, mientras que los hechos específicos, particulares y concluídos que marcan la secuencia del relato (básicamente las acciones que van realizando los personajes del cuento) se expresan con el pretérito perfecto.

La situación que nos traés es muy específica porque ambas acciones se pueden atribuir al fondo de la narración. Lo que sucede por un lado es que es probable que el autor, al concluír la descripción con un tiempo perfecto, esté concluyendo también la narración de ese período para, o bien trasladarse a otra época y continuar la narración allí, o bien acabar la narración/descripción y comenzar otro tipo de discurso (una explicación por ejemplo). Por otra parte, sonaría redundante si hubiesen estado ambos verbos en imperfecto—queda desafinado escribir dos veces 'había', en caso de que se hubiese querido continuar la descripción se podría haber omitido el  segundo verbo, v.g.:

> Antes de la Conquista no había «Argentina» **ni** tampoco una «Argentina colonial». Las extensas áreas de tierra estaban despobladas, la mayoría del territorio era desconocido y los colonizadores tenían grandes esperanzas de encontrar riquezas... (continuación de la descripción)

Hay una segunda posibilidad que consiste en que el *había* esté situado en la época anterior a la Conquista, mientras que el *hubo* sea atemporal. En este caso el autor estaría indicando que en ningún momento de la historia, ya sea antes o después de la Conquista, ha existido una «Argentina colonial»—lo que sea que eso signifique. Aunque esta situación la veo menos probable, podría darse en el caso que continúe la descripción sobre la época pre-Conquista con la siguiente frase.

Como te podrás dar cuenta, la razón por la que eligió el tiempo perfecto para el segundo verbo depende en principio del contexto en el que aparece escrita la frase.

Answer (score 2):

The first part is an affirmation while the second is a denial of a hypothetical affirmation or existence.

> Although everyone knows that "before the conquest, there was no Argentina", the writer is indirectly indicating that "there was no colonial Argentina" to those who hypothetically affirm it.

Perhaps the confusion is in repeating the same verb, another way would be:

> Antes de la Conquista no había «Argentina», como tampoco nunca existió una «Argentina colonial».

---

Un ejemplo:

> Antes de la pandemia, no había restricciones, como tampoco hubo miedo a la extinción humana

It is an affirmation about the restrictions in times of pandemic and a denial of those who later affirmed that the human race would become extinct, comparing both situations to show that one and the other are true, affirming one and denying the other.